# Auto-update solution for PWA Apps

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I want to turn my normal website into a progressive web app. For that everything is finished. The Website is responsible and I already set up a manifest. Now the last part comes to me. The ServiceWorker to save the website to the cache of the device. My problem is that I can not find a simple solution for that. Because for my website it is important that the user runs the new version every time I made an update. Do you know a solution how let the ServiceWorker check if anything changed once the user opens the app and after that delete the old cache and make a new one based on the new files and the new code?
It would be very great, when somebody could provide a code example.
My HTML SIDE:

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
    .then(reg => console.log(reg))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
</script>
```

AND HERE THE sw.js:

```
    self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(
  caches.open('web_pwa').then(cache => cache.add('/'))
));

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(
  caches.open('web_pwa')
    .then(cache => cache.match(event.request))
    .then(response => response || fetch(event.request))
));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short description:** Update SW file a bit and handle removing old cache in `activate` event.

### Detailed description

Whenever you do changes in your code files *(other than `sw.js`)*. You need to trigger both the **install** and **activate** events in service worker. In order to update your changes.

In order to trigger these events the `sw.js` should be updated even a single bit. *(simply atleast a character).*

By convention developers handle this by maintaining **Versioning**. Also it will be easy to **add and delete caches.**

```js
const version = 'v2';

self.addEventListener('install', res => {
  caches.open(version).then(cache => {
    cache.addAll(caches);
  });
  console.log('[sw] Installed successfully :');
  // self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(
  caches.open(version)
    .then(cache => cache.match(event.request))
    .then(response => response || fetch(event.request))
));
```

If you need to directly update the `sw.js` inspite of user's status then uncomment the `self.skipWaiting()` as it skips waiting for activation and gets activated immediately.

Inside `activate` event is where you have to delete the old caches based on cache version.

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
    cacheNames.forEach(function(cacheName) {
      if (cacheName !== version) {
        caches.delete(cacheName);
      }
    });
  });
}
```